# Render Markdown in Flutter that a user can long press and perform custom actions on

Tags: flutter

I'd like to be able to replicate some functionality using Flutter that I've seen in other apps such as Medium. What this offers is a way for the user to long press the text to reveal a custom menu. From this menu, you can then tap Highlight to apply a coloured highlight to the text (screenshot below).

[image: Screenshot of desired functionality]

I've managed to use the [flutter_markdown](https://github.com/flutter/flutter_markdown) package to get part of the way there but there are some limitations:

```
class ArticleWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Markdown(
        data: _myMarkdown,
        selectable: true,
    );
  }
}
```

- `Markdown` internally uses a `SelectableText.rich` When setting the `selectable` attribute to true.
- This uses a `ToolbarOptions` that you cannot change
- Even if you could, the values in here are hard-coded so I couldn't add one for my custom action anyway. There remains [an open issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/31412) to address this.

My question:

Given the above limitations, how can I get close to the functionality described above?
Is there a way to identify what text is highlighted that'll allow be to produce my own menu - even if it doesn't quite look the same as the one above?